# How do I setup lets encrypt for an Azure Linux Service Web App

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt, azure-web-apps

There are plenty of guides on how to set up Lets Encrypt for Azure Windows Web App Services, but I can't find any at all for Linux based services.

Here are two example of such tutorials (that require windows).

- https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SecuringAnAzureAppServiceWebsiteUnderSSLInMinutesWithLetsEncrypt.aspx
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6V_mBo-gnE

In the tutorials above, and all other tutorials I have found you need to use Web App **Extensions** to do the actual updating of the cert every 3 months. But these are **not available on Linux apps**.

This is all you see in the Azure portal when you try to navigate to it.

[image: no extensions allowed]

So, does anyone have any links, or helpful tips on how to set up automated Let's encrypt certificates for Azure Linux Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an easy built in way to issue certs for Linux web apps (or web apps for containers), like there is for Windows. However there is an opensource project called [appservice-acmebot](https://github.com/shibayan/appservice-acmebot) which lets you use Azure Functions to configure these web apps with lets encrypt certificates. This can manage multiple web applications of different types.

Comment: After endless googling I have come to this same conclusion as well. Hope they can get to this issue soon, as I'm guessing most people want cheap HTTPS certs even for Linux.

Comment: I suspect that what you will see is the new Azure free cert offering rolling out more widely, rather than adoption of Let's encrypt

Comment: I think you are right. I'd be fine with it as long as it works for custom domains, and subdomains.